# Eclipse/ Python Importing Dropbox module

Tags: python, eclipse, import, module, dropbox

I downloaded the Dropbox SDK and installed it via Python script, but when I use the code `import dropbox` on the top of my code, it get's red underlined as unknown.
Is there anything additional to consider?

Comment: What happens when you `import dropbox` in the Python terminal?

Comment: the Python plugin works with the Terminal completely fine. Error is in Eclipse i guess. Maybe because i accidentally used different versions of Python and PyDev?

Comment: What does the red underline say?

Comment: Unused import: dropbox
Unresolved import: dropbox
dropbox Found at: cli_client

Comment: Do you, by chance, have a file called dropbox.py? If so, try renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to get it working:

1. Download Dropbox SDK for Python from : https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/python by clicking on "Download Python SDKVersion X.X.X, updated  X, 20XX"
2. Unzip downloaded folder for exmp: "dropbox-python-sdk-2.1.0"
3. Copy the dropbox folder inside "dropbox-python-sdk-2.1.0/dropbox-python-sdk-2.1.0/"
4. Paste it inside the python folder: for exmp in windows :- C:\Python34\Lib\
5. Refresh the project. now it wont give any error.

In short : **Put your downloaded sdk Lib inside the python libraries.**